# facebook application API check if user is application admin in facebook

Tags: facebook-graph-api

i have:

- user facebook data (
  https://graph.facebook.com/btaylor )
- facebook application data (
  https://graph.facebook.com/2439131959
  )

Is somehow possible to get if user is application administrator in facebook with this in my hands?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if your developed application is checking the role of the logged in facebook user or simply your application wants to recognize it's owner or admin, 
then 
http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me%2Faccounts should have that application id listed

### api call:

```
FB.api('/me/accounts', 'get', {"access_token":access_token}, function(response){
    //loop through response to check any application id matches current application id
});
```

### response sample:

```
{
  "name": "app_name",
  "access_token": "current_token_here",
  "category": "Application",
  "id": "your_owned_app_id"
},
{
  "name": "app_name1",
  "access_token": "current_token_here",
  "category": "Application",
  "id": "your_owned_app1_id"
},
```

Comment: mine doesn't... it's empty but I'm an admin on @20 apps.

Comment: try here first http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me%2Faccounts and also permit the app

Comment: @TomLianza make sure you get the `manage_pages` permission from the user.

Comment: manage_pages does not help. I'm not sure this is the answer. orba's solution works correctly!

Answer (score 6):

To get this kind of information you can use FQL:

```
protected function authorizeByFb(){

        $result = $this->fb->api(array(
          'method' => 'fql.query',
          'query'  => "SELECT developer_id FROM developer WHERE application_id='{$appId}' AND developer_id='{$fbUserId}'",
        ));     

        if(count($result)==1){
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I just got this to work using the Facebook JS API:

```
FB.api({ method: 'pages.isAdmin', page_id : fbAppId }, function(response){
    if(response){
        alert('the user is an admin');
    }else{
        alert('the user is not an admin')
    }
});
```

It's using the FB.api method to access the old REST API.  This assumes that you've already called FB.init, so make sure that this comes after your init code.

Cheers,
Jeremy

Answer (score 0):

You can get the signed_request and then check if page_admin = 1

```
<?php
$signed_request = $facebook->getSignedRequest();

$page_admin  = $signed_request["page"]["admin"];
if ( $page_admin == 1 ){ 
echo 'Welcome Admin!';
} 
?>
```

Comment: The poster is asking how to detect if the current user is an admin of the current *application*, not page.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to attempted javascript form above and found this method to work as an alternative now that the old restful api is depreciated.

```
function checkAdmin(fbUID, fbAppID){

   FB.api({

    method: 'fql.query',
    query: 'SELECT role FROM app_role WHERE developer_id ='+fbUID+' AND application_id = '+fbAppID

    },
    function(response) {
       if(response.length){
            alert('User is an Admin');
        }
        else{
            alert('User is not an Admin')
        }
    });
 }
```