# Facebook request change according to different login

Tags: facebook

Will the facebook fetching a tab application differs according to different login?

If I am login as application admin or page admin then facebook fetches the application through POST and if i am login as a normal user, then facebook fetches the page through GET

Comment: Describe more. For example, what are you trying to do in your app, which sdk you are using, what api call you are making and perhaps what unexpected response did you get. Don't tell that you did not even try.

Answer (score 0):

As I know, Facebook integrate with your app (iframe) with only one method (i.e POST). Everything you put on app URL facebook will post to your iframe.

For example `apps.facebook.com/your_app/id/1`, Facebook will POST id=1 to your iframe.

However, you can check an user whether is an app/page admin or not by using Open Graph API:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#admins

I think you question somehow relate to this:[facebook application API check if user is application admin in facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4153356/facebook-application-api-check-if-user-is-application-admin-in-facebook)

Hope this will helps.